# Objective-C strange EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, crash

My code is crashing with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error that I don't know how to debug.

This is the code:

```
NSUInteger lineCount = self.lineBeginnings.count;
NSUInteger lineBeginnings[lineCount];
[self.lineBeginnings getIndexes:lineBeginnings maxCount:lineCount inIndexRange:nil];
```

It crashes on the last line, with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x...)`.

Notice two lines above, it's able to read self.lineBeginnings perfectly, but in the debugger I get:

```
(lldb) p [self lineBeginnings]
error: Trying to put the stack in unreadable memory at: 0x7fff5d15e310.
(lldb) p _lineBeginnings
(NSMutableIndexSet *) $1 = 0x0000610000059b90
(lldb) po _lineBeginnings
[no Objective-C description available]
```

Also lineBeginnings doesn't show up properly in the GUI scope browser (all other variables do) and trying to "View Memory of lineBeginnings" gives a completely empty memory view.

The `lineBeginnings` variable is stored as a strong @property, it's a mutable index set created in the app delegate's init method and never removed while the app is running. There is a background operation queue that writes to it, but it switches to the main thread for all modifications using `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue())`.

I'm not sure how to debug this further? It's hard to reproduce, I have to resize the window for up to a minute (which causes the lineBeginnings variable to be re-created on a background queue, a process that takes ~5 minutes when given 180MB of data), in order to make this crash occur.

It looks like a buffer overrun or something to me? How do I track it down?

The source code for the file is here: https://gist.github.com/abhibeckert/7128740 (the crash is on line 254).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In 180 MB there are probably millions of line beginnings? So you are allocating an array of millions of eight byte words *on the stack*. A thread's stack usually is not that large.

You should allocate the array on the heap, using `malloc`.

Your problem is called a stack overflow. Sounds familiar?

Comment: Thanks, I'm an experienced Obj-C programmer (since OS X 10.0!) who has never properly learned C, so I struggle when I need to drop to low level stuff. So basically you're saying there's a fairly small limit to how large `lineCount` can be? My code is performing soft wrapped text, lineBeginnings is the byte offsets in the data where core text says the line should be wrapped. This is an experiment to rewrite NSTextView to solve some bottlenecks I've run into.

Comment: lineCount is ~ 5.7 million when it crashes. Thanks I'll look into using malloc. NSIndexSet is also the wrong data set to use anyway, since it uses NSRange internally and my indexes are never consecutive, but it wasn't causing any performance issues so I left it in there.

Comment: Exactly. The local (automatic) variable `lineBeginnings` is allocated on the stack. In this case (being a VLA) the stack is adjusted to the right size when the size of the array is known. I'm not sure about the particular size of a thread's stack but as soon as the number of elements exceeds a couple thousand you should switch to heap allocated memory.

Comment: What is the best technique for using malloc() when you don't know how large it needs to be? Usually it will only be a few hundred bytes, but occasionally (if the user opens an unusually large file) it will be hundreds of megabytes or possibly even gigabytes. Should I just malloc 1MB or so and if it runs out malloc some new memory 10x larger and copy the data over, or what? It takes core text minutes to perform line wrapping on a large text file (mysql database dump or whatever), which is why I'm moving away from NSTextView

Comment: You can do the same as before: just allocate the needed buffer. The allocation in a 64 bit process virtually can't fail. And as long as they are not touched, the pages are not mapped and no physical memory is used.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after spending 2 days i found that my getter is calling several time because i was using self in getter.

```
 if(! _openSectionIndexes) _openSectionIndexes = [NSMutableArray new];

if( _openSectionIndexes.count != _requests.count)
{
    for (int i =0; i < _requests.count; i++)
    {
        [self.openSectionIndexes addObject: @(NO)];// here was the problem, replaced it with _openSectionIndexes
    }
}

return _openSectionIndexes;
```